# What is the data annotation for changing nullable and not null data types?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-migrations

I reckon this should be simple for experienced programmers but here it goes. I am working on a project using entity framework code first.I have also enabled migrations and set to auto (Lovely feature).

I stupidly declared one of the datatype wrong in my entity class and now i realised that it wouldn't work with what i was trying to do. Must have been the auto complete feature. But anyways, the field was nullable and now that i have changed it to what i want, it has set the field to "not null".

Originally: `public virtual Byte[] ImageData { get; set; }`

Changed to: `public virtual byte ImageData { get; set; }`

Now that i have changed and built the solution, `update-database -force` will not work and throws an error that:

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ImageData', column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails. The statement has been terminated.
```

Is there a Data Annotation i could use to set this field back to nullable?

eg: `[DataType(DataType.Upload)]`

I have looked through here for a considerable amount of time and i can't seem to find what i am looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the property type to the nullable form `byte?`.

```
public virtual byte? ImageData { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks, i thought that only works with `int` and `Datetime`, i didn't even bother to try. I think i need to read more books :)